# Wordpress Custom SQL Table with UserID Filter for results

Tags: php, mysql

UPDATE: I have realised that I need to use a plugin like PHP Snipping or Insert PHP to make this work, I have updated my screen shots to reflect where Im upto from my research.

The code is working and outputting the right User ID but the SQL is not echoing the Table data, if you have some advice on where I might of gone wrong would be great.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$uid = get_current_user_id();

$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM  sr3_characters WHERE wp_id = $uid" );
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql);
?>
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Race</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php foreach ($results as $value) { echo "$value->char_name<br>"; }; ?></td>
<td><?php foreach ($results as $value) { echo "$value->char_race<br>"; }; ?></td>
<td><?php foreach ($results as $value) { echo "$value->char_gender<br>"; }; ?></td>
<td><?php foreach ($results as $value) { echo "$value->char_age<br>"; }; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: New output screen]

[image: phpmyadmin_1]

[image: phpmyadmin_2]

Comment: Hello @Trev can you explain more like what your expected result like what you want ?

Comment: Hey Im hoping to get a table output with a list of character names i.e

Name [Tim] - Race [Elf] - Gender [Male] - Age [ 75] that belong to the logged in person to Wordpress

Comment: Can you post Screenshot of wp_user and wp_usermeta table for that user it will more clear to see the data .

Comment: No problems, have uploaded it now

Comment: As i have seen in your meta table there is no data saved with Name [Tim] - Race [Elf] - Gender [Male] - Age [ 75] keys in meta_key value so can you tell me is value is saved ?

Comment: Hey, Sorry no the table with in the wordpress database im trying to pull info from is called sr3_characters, see the screen shot recently uploaded, hope this helps.

Comment: You've never assigned a value to the the variable `$char_name` - there's nothing to print. Try a `var_dump( $results );` - your data should be in there.

Comment: Hey Bosco, thanks for that the  addition resulted in data being dumped so it looks like the SQL is working but Its my echo thats not, im getting this now at the top of the page `array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#29176 (39) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["wp_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["char_name"]=> string(3) "Tim" ["char_race"]=> string(3) "Elf" ["char_gender"]=> string(4) "Male" ["char_age"]=> string(2) "45" ["char_desc"]=> string(22) "Tall dark and handsome" ["char_notes"]=> string(22) "Tall dark and.......`  Any tips that will help echo the 2 records to the table below? Ill keep looking too.

Comment: there's no information about your table and its schema in your question, please use the edit link to update your question to include all the related information including any that you've added to the comments here and to the comments on the answers given. Also be aware that you've inserted a variable directly into your SQL which is a security risk, you should have used `$wpdb->prepare` to safely insert the variable `$uid` into the SQL query which would have escaped it for you

Comment: Also is your code complete? `$results` is never used and `$row` is used but it appears out of nowhere and is never defined, is there a missing loop? I suspect the problem here has nothing to do with WordPress but the problem is that you don't know how to loop over items in an array in PHP

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for trying to help, The code in the Original post is updated as I make changes and is as it is in full. I have looked up how to use the `$wpdb->prepare` and got it to work as suggested, thanks for that. I have uploaded 2 screenshots from my phpmyadmin login of the table and the table_structure hope it helps. I have also tried to use a For Each loop foreach as suggested on another comment, `foreach ($results as $value) { echo "$value <br>"; }` but this either crashes the site or doesnt work im still working on it though.

Comment: @Trev `$results` is an array of PHP objects with members corresponding to the names of your columns. So, if your `foreach` loop, you'd use a property accessor operator to get the respective values - `$value->char_name`, for example. More on PHP object properties in [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). Echoing `$value` directly doesn't work as PHP will not automatically serialize a complex object like an object into a string when trying to print it - `var_dump()` and `print_r()` are two mechanisms for printing such an object.

Comment: Ohh awesome, that has helped alot, got major progress, its resulting like I want (not in a proper table, both records are in the one row of the table as aposed to 2 indavidual rows, code and output screen shot updated with where im at so far, Maybe I need to echo the HTML table code with the `$value->char_name` not sure or maybe make like `MyValue = $value->char_name` and then `echo MyValue`. but will keep trying. thanks heaps. If you have any tips that might help get the record into a table let me know please,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The evolution of this question makes it difficult to succinctly answer, but in brief summary:

- Using [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) to construct arbitrary SQL queries to execute against the database helps to mitigate [injection vulnerabilities](https://xkcd.com/327/) by escaping inserted variables. To use it, instead of concatenating or directly inserting variables into the query, use a placeholder for the appropriate type of data, then pass the variable which be inserted in that location in a respectively indexed array as the second argument.
- If this character data is input by end-users, you should also consider [sanitizing the inputs prior to inserting them into the database, and possibly escaping the values prior to displaying them on the front-end](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/) to further mitigate the risk of injection vulnerability and to prevent end users from displaying arbitrary HTML/JavaScript when their character data is displayed.
- Queries executed via [`$wpdb->get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) return an array of objects, with the properties on the objects being named after the columns in the SQL table. If you prefer to work with arrays instead (either associative or numerically indexed) you can change this behavior by passing one of the predefined constants in as the second argument.
- When printing a non-primative data structure such as an object, PHP won't automatically serialize the object into a string for display. `print_r()` is capable of printing most common data structures, but `var_dump()` is a invaluable development aide when you're not sure of the type of the value.

All of that said, since each object in the array represents one row from your database table and since HTML tables are constructed one row at a time, you can simply use a single `foreach` loop to place the relevant values from each item into a cell:

```php
<?php
global $wpdb;
$uid = get_current_user_id();

$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `sr3_characters` WHERE `wp_id` = %s", array( $uid ) );
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
?>
<html>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Race</th>
        <th scope="col">Gender</th>
        <th scope="col">Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach( $results as $row ) { ?>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo esc_html( $row->char_name ); ?></th>
        <td><?php echo esc_html( $row->char_race ); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->char_gender; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->char_age; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Bosco, thanks so much for the help, it worked perfectly and has given me the informaiton I need to progress with page 2 which shows the RPG char sheet in full detail. Thanks again I appreciate the help.

Comment: Awesome man! I'm glad we got it all sorted out :). Consider [accepting the answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in order to mark the question as resolved and net us both a little reputation!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the values of your custom table, `wp_get_current_user()` is probably returning the wrong user compared to what is in your table. Assuming this is running on the frontend, and you want to check the current user, it would be better to use `get_current_user_id()` and parse that to your query.

I would also suggest that you sanitise all your queries before putting them through get_results. See here https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Database

Comment: The Table Holds somthing like the following ID [1] - wp_id [1] - Name [Tim] - Race [Elf] - Gender [Male] - Age [ 75] & row 2 of the table is ID [2] - wp_id [1] - Name [Bob] - Race [Troll] - Gender [female] - Age [45]  <br/>Thanks for the tip I tired to do `$uid = get_current_user_id();` and then echo that line uid: `<!--?php echo $uid; ?-->` but it comes up blank result from the echo

Comment: Hey I have uploaded a screenshot of the sr3_characters table for you now, hope this extra bit helps.

Comment: Where is this code running? If `get_current_user_id` returns nothing, it usually means that the code is firing before the init action.

Comment: Hey thanks again for helping, I have put the code in the wordpress page, (I put a new screen shot to help you see), I have a feeling maybe what im trying to do wont work, not sure if It can be done like this in the block/code editor

Comment: Update: I have realised that I need to use a plugin like PHP Snipping or Insert PHP to make this work, I have updated my screen shots to reflect where Im upto from my research.

The code is working and outputting the right User ID but the SQL is not echoing the Table data, if you have some advice on where I might of gone wrong would be great. PS: new screen shots are uploaded

Comment: It's because the rows are returned as an array. So you need to loop over the array to output the values. See this - https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_foreach.asp

Comment: Hey Digitalchild, I have tried to use a For Each loop foreach as suggested on another comment, `foreach ($results as $value) { echo "$value <br>"; }` but this either crashes the site or doesnt work im still working on it though as the w3schools site have got alot of info but it doesnt help me this time to explain what Im doing, and to echo it out to the table, do I put the table between the two `{  and  }` not sure PS: code updated also to include `$wpdb->prepare`